My LSTM RNN model always gives me the same output for every prediction, what can I do?
I have a dataset of trajectories (several float arrays) that I want to classify (0 or 1, depending on the type of trajectory).
                    features = np.column_stack((
                    sat.inclinations,
                    sat.mean_motions,
                    sat.eccentricities,
                    sat.semimajor_axes,
                    sat.orbital_energy
                    
                ))
                feature_sequences.append(features)
                labels.append(sat.manoeuvrability)
        
        X = pad_sequences(feature_sequences, padding='post', dtype='float32')
        y = np.array(labels)
        return train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

I thought using a LSTM RNN is a good idea for classifying a series of data:
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'),  # LSTM layer
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10),  # Another LSTM layer
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),  # Dense layer for further processing
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),  # Dropout for regularization
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # Output layer for binary classification
        ])

The problem
My predictions seem to be way too similar to be, for example 0.56463885 and 0.56463975 for completely different inputs. Training another time results in a similar problem, just with a different value. Validation and accuracy seem to converge very fast.
What I tried

I tried different scalers, e.g MinMax and StandardScaler.
Gradient clipping: Maybe a vanishing gradient is the problem, so I used this optimizer I found in another answer:  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=1.0)
Different batch sizes
class weights, because the data is indeed a little bit unbalanced.

What can I do?
I supsect that the architecture is weird, but I do not know how I should do that better. Any ideas or help is appreciated.
